# Is a reference in a View to a ViewModel (which is its DataContext) in any way detrimental to MVVM pattern?

Tags: wpf, design-patterns, mvvm

Let's say a `ViewModel` publishes an `Event` and a `View` which is using that VM as its `DataContext` subscribes to that `Event` by obtaining a reference to the VM by casting its `DataContext` to VM instance:

```
vm = DataContext as MainViewModel;
if (vm == null) return;
vm.SomeUIRelatedNotice += DoSomethingUIRelated;
```

The way I see this, the VM ramains decoupled and its testability is in no way affected, and the View already has a reference to the VM so I see no problem with this at all but I want to hear from the MVVM purists if they think this is bad design with negative impact on the MVVM pattern and if so why?

Comment: there's nothing wrong with this at all, IMO. All of WPF data binding is just views wiring up events on their view models, it's just hidden behind the scenes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the view model is not performing any view logic itself, I don't consider this to be breaking the MVVM pattern.

It looks like in your case the view model is trying to interact and direct the view somehow, so you should probably know that there are other ways to achieve such behavior which are considered to be more pure MVVM:

- MVVM Light Toolkit's [`Messenger` service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj694937.aspx)
- Prism's [`EventAggregator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) or its [interaction patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405494%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec10)

Comment: This is not about a specific case, the idea is to discuss the pattern in general...

Comment: I agree. The View already knows about the VM (most likely so it can specify a `DataTemplate` for it), so there's no harm in referencing it in the code-behind for View-Specific code only. It's definitely not ideal, but I see no harm in doing so to overcome some of the UI's limitations. I also agree that there are better ways to do this specific example, such as a messaging system. Ideally your View should not be controlling application flow, such as attaching events to the VM :)

Answer (score 2):

View knowing a VM is not wrong at all and like you mentioned is perfectly fine.

In such cases, the question I ask myself is

**"Would doing this X action make my VM's break testability? or hinder the scope of testability in my business logic?"**

If answer is "Yes" - You're kind-of heading down the wrong path. If "No" go right ahead. In my opinion that's all there is to MVVM. It helps you unit test logic and classes which we couldnt before with things like MVC and tight coupling.

As you arent unit-testing view related stuff to a large extent, this wouldn't affect your MVVM "true-ness" in any way.

**Side-Note**

While I would stick with my above opinion. One thing is, have you considered using a `Messenger` [Simple Tutorial of MVVM Light's Messenger](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/mvvm-light-whats-messenger) / `EventAggregator` pattern. With a `Messenger` pattern, your VM would be just publishing the Message's and you're Views could essentially just subscribe to these messages without even having to refer to the VM (make the message type custom strong if you want uniqueness). This way you do not have to do the whole casting from `DataContext` and can also unit-test the Message publishing from the VM perfectly fine.